# Repeating Numbers In Integer Array (Java Basic Level) & Time Complexity

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, duplicates

I have created an integer array and initialized this array with random number using Math.random().

I am trying to print duplicate numbers in array without using Arraylist or Hashset. 
My code (in progress):

```
public class Test{
    public static final int Length = 20;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a[]= new int[Length];
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            a[i]=(int)(Math.random()*Length);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        isDuplicate(a);
        System.exit(0);
    }//eof main
    public static void isDuplicate(int a[]){
        System.out.print("Duplicates: ");
        boolean test[] = new boolean[Length];
        for(int i=0; i<test.length; i++){
            test[i]=false;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
            if(test[a[i]]==false){
                test[a[i]]=true;
            }
            else
                System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }//eof isDuplicate
}
```

Sample Output:

```
    16 15 12 7 0 7 2 14 12 18 1 8 2 15 4 5 6 5 12 7 
Duplicates: 7 12 2 15 5 12 7 

The correct output has to be : 7 12 2 15 5
```

It works fine but when a number in array repeating more than two it prints number more than one.
How can I fix it ? On the other hand I have tried to calculate time complexity of this algorithm, is this O(n) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a boolean array use another integer array, since you are filling up with elements which can be at the most 20 you can create an Integer array of size 20 and every time you read a number do this, assuming the array of size 20 is called 'count'.

```
int count[] = new int[Length];
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    count[a[i]]++;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if(count[i] > 1)
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

This will print out the numbers that appear more than once.

Comment: It should be `count[a[i]]++` instead of `count[i]++`

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're dead set on not using an ArrayList (though this would be easiest), you can make a boolean array with the length being the range of possible numbers selected through your Math.random() function (in this case 0 through 19, meaning the range is 20).

```
private static boolean[] duplicatedNumbers = new boolean[20];
private static int[] numbers = new int[20];
for(int i = 0; i < duplicatedNumbers.length; i++){
    duplicatedNumbers[i] = false;
}
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    numbers[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 20);
}
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){//this for loop finds out which ones are duplicated
    for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++){
        if(j!=i && numbers[j] == numbers[i]){
            duplicatedNumbers[numbers[j]] = true;
        }
    }
}
System.out.print("Numbers: ");
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    System.out.print(numbers[i] + ", ");
}
System.out.println();
System.out.print("Duplicated Numbers: ");
for(int i = 0; i < duplicatedNumbers.length; i++){
    if(duplicatedNumbers[i]){
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
    }
}
```

Edit: Fixed and tested.